# How to combine multiple rows to use as column names when importing excel file in pandas?

Tags: pandas, excel, dataframe

[image: here]

Given a file containing two header rows, is there a way I can arrive at column names B, C, D, E, F, G either completely omitting A or prefixing it to B, C, D using pandas `read_excel` function without setting them manually using names argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the spreadsheet with a *MultiIndex* header, then conditionally flatten it :

```
df = (
    (tmp:=pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=[0, 1]))
        .set_axis([c0 if c1.startswith("Unnamed") else c1 # to ommit A
        # and if you need to concatenate both levels, use `else f"{c0}-{c1}"` 
                   for (c0, c1) in tmp.columns], axis=1)
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

       B     C     D     E     F     G     H
0   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
1   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
2   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
3   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
4   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
5   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
6   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
7   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
8   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
9   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
10  data  data  data  data  data  data  data
11  data  data  data  data  data  data  data
12  data  data  data  data  data  data  data
13  data  data  data  data  data  data  data
```

With a prefix :

```
     A-B   A-C   A-D     E     F     G     H
0   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
1   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
2   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
3   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
4   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
5   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
6   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
7   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
8   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
9   data  data  data  data  data  data  data
10  data  data  data  data  data  data  data
11  data  data  data  data  data  data  data
12  data  data  data  data  data  data  data
13  data  data  data  data  data  data  data
```